# What is the Timeline for Entry-Level Mathematics Job Search?

Tags: job-search

I'm applying for mathematics jobs (entry-level, non-tenure) in the United States from abroad.

I've googled and read the [obvious articles](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/loci/joma/a-timeline-for-a-job-search-in-mathematics-introduction) on this topic and I still have big questions about the process.

Are the stages of a successful application: phone interview > in-person seminar > offer?

Given that I'm applying from abroad, how will the phone interview work? Is it usually a Skype interview or skipped?

I've heard that offers usually go out in January at later, but if I do not receive a phone interview or any acknowledgement by mid-December, does that mean the application is likely rejected?

And if the "review date" for the application is earlier than normal, e.g. early-mid November, does that imply that the timeline is also earlier, so that no acknowledgement around early December means likely rejection?

Comment: "Entry-level non-tenure" could mean a few different things, with different interview processes.  Are you talking about tenure-track assistant professorships, postdocs, full-time lecturer positions, teaching-orienting visiting assistant professorships, part-time adjunct positions, ...?

Comment: I'm talking about non-tenure assistant professorships and postdocs, which seem to be the most common positions offered.

Comment: I am still not sure what you mean by "non-tenure assistant professorships".  Are these permanent positions that will eventually be eligible for tenure (i.e. tenure-track), or temporary positions that will end after a certain number of years (usually called **visiting** assistant professor)?

Comment: Yes, visiting assistant professor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation for postdocs and non-tenure-track visiting assistant professorships (VAP for short) is rather different than for tenure-track assistant professorships.  In particular, postdoc and VAP positions often do not have an in-person interview.

I would expect there will certainly be a phone (or Skype) interview.  This wouldn't be skipped simply because you are coming from abroad.  If ordinary phone is inconvenient or expensive for you, it's fine to ask that Skype or another alternative be used instead.  Some committees may have their own VOIP/videoconference solutions.

It's likely the case that the initial shortlist would be contacted within a few weeks after the application deadline, so if you don't hear anything within that time, you probably didn't make the initial shortlist.  However, if the committee interviews those candidates and doesn't find enough that they like, they may go back to their application pool and contact some more candidates.  So all hope is not lost.

A couple other notes:

- VAP positions are often posted much later, because they are sometimes used to temporarily fill a position that comes open because of an unexpected departure.  It's not uncommon for them to be posted in February or March or even later, with a quick deadline.  So if you're looking for such positions, keep your eyes open.
- For VAP positions that are primarily meant to fill teaching needs (e.g. with a load of 4 courses per year or more), the department may not be interested in hiring candidates from abroad, because of visa issues (unless of course you are already a US citizen or permanent resident).  This is not such an issue for postdocs.

Comment: *It's not uncommon for them to be posted in February or March, with a quick deadline.* --- The two times I applied for VAP's, I didn't even start looking at the positions until mid-April (early May for the 2nd time, in fact), as I was involved in tenure-track campus visits and such Feb.-April (typically they start a few weeks after the January AMS/MAA meeting), and quite a few were not posted until April, with interviews (sometimes by phone, but most of mine were campus visits) conducted May-June. There were a few still open in July, but for most people probably last-resort places.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro: Good point.  Updated.